# How to prevent an event from being called multiple times in a prism module

Tags: c#, module, prism

### Problem

Event subscribed on `EventAggregator` called multiple times.

```
public class ModuleViewModel
{
    public ModuleViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
    {
        eventAggregator.GetEvent<ModuleEvent>().Subscribe(OnEventReceived);
    }


    private void OnEventReceived(ModuleEvent event)
    {

    }
}
```

### Cause

Event subscribed in viewmodel's `ctor` contained in prism module.
The main application has several Views, each with a `Region`. And they display or use same module. 
As a result, the module is initialized multiple times.

### Condition

###### Modules are loaded from directory in Main Application's App class.

```
public partial class App : PrismApplication
{
    protected override IModuleCatalog CreateModuleCatalog()
    {
        string modulePath = @".\Modules";
        if (Directory.Exists(modulePath) == false)
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(modulePath);
        }

        var catalog = new DirectoryModuleCatalog() { ModulePath = modulePath};
        foreach(var module in catalog.Modules)
        {
            module.InitializationMode = InitializationMode.WhenAvailable;
        }

        return catalog;
    }
    // ...
}
```

###### Main Applications each view have region

```
public class Module : IModule
{
    // ...

    public void OnInitialized(IContainerProvider containerProvider)
    {
        var regionManager = containerProvider.Resolve<IRegionManager>();
        regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("Region1", typeof(ModuleView));
        regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("Region2", typeof(ModuleView));
    }

    public void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
    {
        containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<ModuleView, ModuleViewViewModel>();
    }
}
```

###### Module doesn't have data.

When module displayed, main application send configuration via event.
Also when module run, main application send configuration via event.

###### Only one view of main application is displayed at a time.

---

Edit : Text is not clear to identify the problem. I've been renewed.

Comment: Try a lock : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/lock  or a WaitHandle : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.waithandle.waitone?view=net-7.0

Comment: @jdweng I don't understand. Can a `lock` or `waithandle` cause an event to fire only once?

Comment: The real issue is when two events try to execute the same code at the same time.  You can only have one process execute the event at one time, all others have to wait.  A waithandle can only allow one event to fire at one time.  It will allow one process to fire an event and then cause all other processes to wait until first is finished running the event.

Comment: @jdweng Sorry, My explanation isn't good enough.
It doesn't matter that 'Event' fires sequentially.
The problem is that multiple instances of modules that perform exactly the same class are created, and as a result, Same events are unconditionally processed multiple times.
I want the event to be processed only once, and I've thought of ways to do that, #1 and #2.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `module` ? Prism's modules aren't created or called by views, they're loaded, initialized and thrown away during app initialization. Are you talking about view models?

Comment: Make methods static so only one can be executed at one time.  Than you can use lock and/or add code to remove duplicates in the static method.

Comment: @Haukinger Each view included in the Main Application has ContentControl including prism:region.
and the module is
Register to Region through `RegionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("ContentRegion", typeof(ModuleView));` in `IModule:OnInitialized`.
Depending on the `InitializationMode` of `Module`, when the App is loaded or the View of the Main Application is displayed, the Module's `ctor` is called as many as the registered `Region`.
Here comes the problem. Events `subscribed` by the ctor are also `subscribed` as many times as `ctor` is called.

Comment: @jdweng Event handlers use member variables and call virtual methods to validate event commands. Also the static ctor has no parameters so you can't use Eventaggregator. I don't know where to use static.

Answer (score 0):

I hope there is a better way. But I couldn't find any other way.

The problem is each call of `regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion` make ViewModel.
So i made viewmodel to singleton. 
And when the main application view changes to another view, it disables the region and resets the module's view model configuration.

```
public class Module : IModule
{
    // ...

    public void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
    {
        containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<ModuleViewViewModel>();
        containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<ModuleView, ModuleViewViewModel>();
    }
}
```

Comment: `private MyModuleViewViewModel _viewModel;` does not make sense because `MyModule` is garbage collected after returning from `OnInitialized`. The module's meant to register stuff only, not to exist on its own.

Comment: @Haukinger Then how about `containerRegistry.RegisterInstance<MyModuleViewViewModel>(new MyModuleViewViewModel())`? I think it is necessary because `RegisterInstance` creates an instance of ViewModel.

Comment: if you want a singleton, just use `containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<MyModuleViewModel>()`, `RegisterInstance` only makes sense if you have the instance at hand already. Singleton view models are a bad idea, though, you better have a good architectural plan that actually requires this. More likely, you want a singleton _service_ that's then consumed by regular (i.e. transient) view models.

Comment: @Haukinger You are right. Singleton view model is a bad idea. Singletons guarantee events to fire only once, but cause more problems due to data sharing in multiple view. Thanks to you, I think I know a little bit about what the problem is. But still can't figure out how to fix it.